# Google Tables (Area 120) - How to authenticate and insert row to existing table (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I need help to authenticate and insert row with 4 columns to google tables using Python.

Here is github of google's project:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/main/packages/google-area120-tables